# Zeroes of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Where can I find a proof/reference for the following fact?

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function with a zero of order $n$ at $z = 0$. Then for sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $a$ with $0 < |a| < \delta$, $f(z) = a$ has exactly $n$ roots in the disc $|z| < \epsilon$.

Comment: First you have $\delta$, and then you have $a$... anyway the series for your holomorphic function will look like $c_1 z^n+c_2 z^{n+1}+\cdots$, no?

Comment: A reference is IV.7.4 in Conway's *Functions of one complex variable*.  I think there was a question about this on this site, but I do not know the link.

Comment: Great, found the theorem in Conway, thanks

Comment: I just found the question I was thinking of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35304/proof-that-1-1-analytic-functions-have-nonzero-derivative.  Duplicate?

Answer (score 7):

A reference is IV.7.4 in J.B. Conway's *Functions of one complex variable*.

$_{\text{This was copied from a comment in an attempt to get the question off of the Unanswered list.}}$