# One-to-one analytic maps are proper

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ be 1-1 and analytic on open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$. If $z_n \in \Omega \to \partial \Omega$ then prove $f(z_n) \to \partial f(\Omega)$ in the sense that $f(z_n)$ eventually lies outside each compact subset of $f(\Omega)$. This property means $f$ is *proper*.

I thought of proof by contradiction, if $\{f(z_n)\}$ is inside a compact set then there is a limit point inside $f(\Omega)$, does this show any contradiction?

Comment: Is $\Omega$ a subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @AreaMan yes, open subset

Comment: Can you see that $f^{-1}$ is a continuous function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the open mapping theorem, which tells you, that non-constant analytic maps on connected domains are open maps. Using this and the injectivity of your map, you can prove that $f$ is an open map. Thus, the inverse map is continuous and hence, your map is proper (by the continuity of the inverse map, the preimage of compact sets are compact).

**Added:** Write $\Omega= \bigcup_{n\in I} U_n$ with $U_n$ being the connected components of $\Omega$. Note that $f$ restricted to any $U_n$ is an open map as the $U_n$ are open sets. If $V\subseteq \Omega$ is an open set, then we get by injectivity

$$ f(V) = \bigcup_{n\in I} f(U_n \cap V), $$

which is open.

**Alternative proof:** Injective analytic maps have nonzero derivative ([Why do injective holomorphic functions have nonzero derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398637/why-do-injective-holomorphic-functions-have-nonzero-derivative)) and thus by the inverse function theorem, $f$ is a local (analytic) diffeomorphism on its image. By injectivity $f$ is a global (analytic) diffeomorphism on its image and is therefore a proper map.

Comment: What if $\Omega$ is not connected?

Comment: @Garou I've added some more details. Please let me know, if something is unclear.