# Möbius transformation/biholomophic funtion

Tags: holomorphic-functions, mobius-transformation

I have to show, that the Möbius transformation $$ T(z) = \frac{z-z_0}{1-\bar{z_0}z}$$
is an biholomorphic function on $ \mathbb{D}$.
$ \mathbb{D}:=\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1 \}$ and $z_0 \in  \mathbb{D}$.
I know the following theorem:
Is $ \mathbb{D}$ convex, T an holomorphic funtion and $Re T'(z)>0 $ in  $ \mathbb{D}$. Then T is biholomorphic.
So I have to calculate $Re T'(z) $ - 
$$ T(x+iy) = \frac{x+iy-(a+ib)}{1-\bar{(a+ib)}(x+iy)} $$ with $ z=x+iy, \ z_0=a+ib$
Is this the right way? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(z)$ is the quotient of two holomorphic functions, so it is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$. The inverse, $T^{-1}(z)=\frac{z+z_0}{1+\bar{z_0}z}$, is also holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$ for the same reason. Thus, T(z) is biholomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$.

To show that the image of T is $\mathbb{D}$ using maximum modulus principle: 
If $|z|=1$, then $z=e^{i\theta}$. Then we have,
$$T(z)=\frac{e^{i\theta}-z_0}{1-\bar{z_0}e^{i\theta}}$$
From which,
$$T(z)=\frac{e^{i\theta}-z_0}{e^{i\theta}(e^{-i\theta}-\bar{z_0})}$$
Let $\alpha=e^{i\theta}-z_0$. Then,
$$T(z)=\frac{\alpha}{e^{i\theta}\bar{\alpha}}=e^{-i\theta}\frac{\alpha}{\bar{\alpha}}$$.
and we conclude that $|T(z)|=|e^{-i\theta}||\frac{\alpha}{\bar{\alpha}}|=1$.
By maximum modulus principle, for $z\in \mathbb{D}$ we must have $|T(z)|<1$ as desired.

Comment: Don't I have to show that the image of T is in $ \mathbb{D}$?

Comment: If you are asking if T is an automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ then yes. I would recommend using the maximum modulus principle to show this.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506058/show-that-left-frac-alpha-beta1-bar-alpha-beta-right-1-when

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link. How would you apply this principle?

Comment: see my edit for details

Comment: Thank you:). Can i say that T is conformal, because  T is a Möbius transformation?

Comment: What definition of conformal mapping are you using?

Comment: Hello, f is an holomorphic function and $ f'(z_0) \ne 0$, then f is conformal.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can prove that if $f$ is injective then $f'(z) \neq 0$. Then $T(z)$ will satisfy your definition.

Comment: Would you show this by definition, also $ T(z_1)=T(z_2) \rightarrow z_1=z_2 $

Comment: No, it is more involved. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398637/why-do-injective-holomorphic-functions-have-nonzero-derivative

Comment: When i prove this theorem, i have to show anyway that f is injektive?

Comment: $T$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$ ... by definition it is injective.

Comment: Ok sorry. I forgot that. Thank you. I think it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of that theorem. The natural way of doing this concists in finding the inverse of $T$, which is$$z\mapsto\frac{z+z_0}{1+\overline{z_0}z}.$$

Comment: Thank you. But how do i know now that T is biholomorphic?

Comment: Because it is holomorphic and its inverse is holomorphic too.

Comment: I see. T is also bijectiv. Then i can say, that T is biholomorphic?. Why is T biholomorphic in $\mathbb{D} $?

Comment: You'll have to prove that $\lvert z\rvert<1\implies\bigl\lvert f(z)\bigr\rvert<1$.

Comment: I would argue like that: $ |z-z_0|<1 $ , $ \$|\bar{z_0}z|<1 \rightarrow |1-\bar{z_0}z| <1 $. But how can i argue that the qoutient is less then 1.