# Show that a certain holomorphic function is not injective

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-integration

Currently working on a head-scratcher:

Let $f: B_1(0) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic, s.t.:
For $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\vert z \vert = \frac{1}{2}$ it holds:
$$\vert f'(z) - z\exp(z) \vert < \frac{1}{2}\exp(\Re(z))$$

Then f is not injective.

I'm not really sure how to approach this. Has anyone ever seen such a problem before and has any intuition on how to approach it? I just don't see how  a statement about the derivative would imply something about the original function.

Comment: I have tried to answer your question. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|z| = 1/2$ is
$$
\vert f'(z) - z\exp(z) \vert < \frac{1}{2}\exp(\Re(z)) = |z\exp(z) |
$$
which implies by Rouché's theorem that $f'$ and $z\exp(z)$ have the same number of zeros in the disk $|z|< 1/2$.

So $f'$ has a zero in that disk, and therefore $f$ is not injective (see for example [Proof that 1-1 analytic functions have nonzero derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/35304/42969)).